# quazip: windows ming32w-make error

Tags: qt, mingw32, quazip

I am trying to compile the quazip source, under wdinwso 7 with QT5.4.

I tried compiling unders VS 2013, but the rc.exe file is not found. I made sure that the rc.exe and dll were in the kits and SDK folders for both vs2013 and vs2010.

So I followed this:  http://www.maefloresta.com/portal/quazip

When i do so, I get the following error message, and am not sure where to start looking.

```
C:\development\QTCommon\quazip>mingw32-make
cd quazip\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\development\QT\5.4\5.4\msvc2013_64\bin\
qmake.exe C:\development\QTCommon\quazip\quazip\quazip.pro -o Makefile ) && ming
w32-make -f Makefile
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/development/QTCommon/quazip/quazip'
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/development/QTCommon/quazip/quazip'
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -FS -O2 -MD -Zc:strictStrings -W3 -w34100 -w341
89 -GR -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQUAZIP_BUILD -DNOMINMAX -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE
_LIB -DNDEBUG -I"." -I"C:\development\QT\5.4\5.4\msvc2013_64\Src\qtbase\src\3rdp
arty\zlib" -I"C:\development\QT\5.4\5.4\msvc2013_64\include" -I"C:\development\Q
T\5.4\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore" -I"release" -I"C:\development\QT\5.4\5.4\m
svc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013" -Forelease\ @<<
<< was unexpected at this time.
Makefile.Release:116: recipe for target '{release}.cpp{release\}.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [{release}.cpp{release\}.obj] Error 255
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/development/QTCommon/quazip/quazip'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/development/QTCommon/quazip/quazip'
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'sub-quazip-make_first' failed
mingw32-make: *** [sub-quazip-make_first] Error 2
```

The makefile.release line found from quazip:

```
####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .cc .cxx

{release}.cpp{release\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Forelease\ @<<
    $<
    <<
```

Any help would be great, for either the make or the vs 2013 issues.

Cheers.

Comment: Your mingw32-make looks in the msvc2013 directories. It's your problem. If you'll compile with mingw, you need to use its headers and libraries. But I don't understand, have you installed mingw separately than Qt? Edit: If so, you might need to define the include and lib directories in quazip.pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are following the instructions from the link provided (http://www.maefloresta.com/portal/quazip) probably the origin of the problem could come because you are not build properly the QuaZIP libraries or because your include path or library path are wrong.

If you want a full example that works perfectly about how to use QuaZIP in Qt, I recommend you to check this entry of my blog: http://www.antonioborondo.com/2014/10/22/zipping-and-unzipping-files-with-qt/

Comment: The example works best on a Linux environment. Your blog is a better example. @Antonio Borondo

Comment: @Arnej65, the example works the same in Windows and Linux environments. Actually, the example in my blog run in Windows. The only difference between both should be the format to write the path to the different libraries.